# Editing URL's on Drupal for a VIEW

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-7, aliases

I want edit path alias for a view, I know how to edit regular content pages

*admin>config>URL aliases>add aliases*

However for a **view** that's pulling in products for example is there a different approach here? I've tried adding the exact path which has %% in it and changed it to a URL with hyphens, however that doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Extended Path Aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt) module.